# Simulation Nodes: How is Delta Time different from Scene Time?

Tags: simulation-nodes

How is Delta Time different from Scene Time in Simulation Nodes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scene time - how much time in frames or seconds, has passed since the beginning of the animation.

Delta time - how much time has passed, in seconds, from the last evaluation (last frame).

Delta time is a typical value used in simulations and  game loops independent of fps, for example I used it here, named `dt`:

[Distributed interaction visualization](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/238409/60486)

```py
def brain(dt, memory, gps):
```

You could implement delta time yourself by reading the scene time, passing it to sim output and subtracting current scene time from the previous scene time.

Answer (score 6):

### **Clarifying pointers:**

---

**Delta Time in simulation, keeps things steady:**

[image]

---

**Scene Time plugged into simulation, makes things exponential:**

[image]

---

**The value in 'Simulation Output' can be used as 'Time' for some things:**

[image]

Comment: Is Delta Time meant to accommodate sub-frame steps, eventually?

Comment: I also would love to know that ...

Comment: Manu .. The 4.0 manual suggests you can set substeps in the properties menu, and also shows a different interface for Baking. I can't think of another sensible meaning for Delta Time, not yet implemented. I could be wrong, of course.